# How can I render a Windows Azure report in Salesforce?

Tags: visualforce

We have data SQL Server database with a Windows Azure data layer with prebuilt reports that we need to shed some visibility on in Salesforce. What is the best way to display these? I tried a new tab, with a Visualforce page and iframe. However, the user has to login in the iframe to access the reports. How can I make it so the user doesn't have to log in?

Comment: Just to avoid complications are these reports dynamically changing all day along (or) just some static reports that get updated every once in a while. If these are static reports mentioned here I would recommend syncing the reports between SF and SQL by using data loading tools else you will have to look at webservices as an option if you are a developer to authenticate and access reports between SF and SQL

Comment: They would be reports that are only updated everyone once in a while. However, I believe web services is the route the company wants to take. Where could I find out more information about how to get started with web services? Many thanks!

Comment: I do not know much of SQL server , by doing a google search I landed up in this blog, not sure if this could help you too much  : http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/04/18/sql-server-using-ssis-to-import-csv-file-into-salesforce-online-database-with-dotconnect-for-salesforce-from-devart/